# MySQL: dynamic "IN" clause from a split on a string

Tags: mysql, dynamic, split, explode

I have a a table "wordlist", with a score attributed to each word: either 1 or -1:

```
id | name | val
1, 'hello', 1,
2, 'world', -1
3, 'test', 1,
...
```

I also have a table "texts" containing texts:

```
id | text | score
1, 'hello world', 0
2, 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet...', 0
...
```

I'd like to update the field "score" from the table "texts" with this rule:

score = sum(wordlist.val) where each word of the sentence is present in the wordlist.

I tried this way, but it's not working:

```
update texts as t set score=(select sum(val) from wordlist where word in (concat('\'', replace(t.text,' ','\',\''),'\'')))
```

I have more than 500K lines of data to process, so I'd rather use only MySQL, without using any PHP.

Thanks in advance if you have a solution!

I wish there was an explode() function in MySQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use FIND_IN_SET(), like this:

```
select
  texts.*, sum(val)
from
  texts left join wordlist
  on find_in_set(wordlist.name, replace(texts.`text`, ' ', ','))>0
group by texts.id
```

if you need to update your table, you could use this:

```
update texts inner join (
  select texts.id, sum(val) as score
  from texts left join wordlist
       on find_in_set(wordlist.name, replace(texts.`text`, ' ', ','))>0
  group by texts.id) s
  on texts.id=s.id
set texts.score=s.score
```

Comment: Nice, `find_in_set()` should be fast!  May need a `group by` somewhere though?

Comment: @ebyrob yes, i forgot a group by, sorry :) `find_in_set` is nice, but i don't think it's faster than a `like`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RLIKE` to do a Regex match with word boundaries, like this:

```
UPDATE texts SET score = text_scores.score
FROM (
  SELECT texts.id as text_id, SUM(wordlist.val) as score
  FROM texts
  JOIN wordlist
    ON texts.text RLIKE CONCAT('[[:<:]]', wordlist.name, '[[:>:]]')
  GROUP BY texts.id) text_scores
WHERE id = text_scores.text_id
```

Comment: Might also work with regular like: `ON CONCAT(' ', texts.text, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ', wordlist.name, ' %')`.